# export a c++ function with it's raw function name

Tags: c++, dllexport

I'm writing a dll, which exports a function

```
extern "C"
__declspec(dllexport)
std::list<string> create() {
return std::list<string>();
}
```

the compiler complains:

> error C2526: 'create' : C linkage function cannot return C++ class 'std::list<_Ty>'

if I remove the extern "C", the function name exported would be:
?create@@YA?AV?$list@PAUanalyzer@@V?$allocator@PAUanalyzer@@@std@@@std@@XZ

I want the name to be clean, so I added extern "C", now it conflicts

Any other way can get a clean function name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `extern "C"` you tell the compiler to create a function that can be called from other languages than C++ (most notably C). However, no other language than C++ have `std::list`, so it can not create such a function because the return type is part of the function signature in C++. And if you don't create a function which has C-compatible return type (or arguments) you can not create an `extern "C"` function.

If you're going to use the DLL from a C++ program there is no need for the `extern "C"` part. The C++ compiler and linker will be able to handle the mangled name without problems anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the name to be clean, because other people may use this dll and call LoadLibrary&GetProcAddress("create") to use the "create()" function...

after some google job, I found
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:create=?create@@YA?AV?$list@PAUanalyzer@@V?$allocator@PAUanalyzer@@@std@@@std@@XZ")
, which creates a link to the very-long-name-function,  I don't know if there is any better way?

Comment: @aj3423: Better way is not to return `std::list`. A linked list is very easy to implement with pointers. Templates have many advantages, but sadly interoperability is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a pointer instead of the object.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) std::list<std::string>* createAllocated()
{
    return new std::list<std::string>();
}
```

Due to the nature of C++, the caller will need to have the compatible ABIs.